# Xdebug installed on Mac Native apache

Tags: php, apache, debugging, xdebug

I am trying to get XDEBUG up and going but having trouble getting the cookie to show. Below is what is put in my php.ini file. I restarted apache. I did a phpinfo() call and I do see xdebug enabled and the settings set. But when I do a `localhost/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1` I am expecting to see a Cookie set to 1 in my browser right ?

```
zend_extension ="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
```

when I run php -m I do not see it but I do see it in phpinfo

Answer (score 0):

couldnt figure the exact answer but I went and downloaded the php.ini.default file from repo and set the following in the php ini

```
zend_extension ="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.idekey=foo
xdebug.profiler_enable=On
```

and it worked. could of been because of remote host. who knows. it worked. this is the bare minimum configurations for mac and this is if your going by the follwing installations for xdebug on mac

http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/installing-php-xdebug-extension-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion.html